# Moving position of UILabel for a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have an UITableView with many cells in it. There are also a few labels in it with an image. But the image is not in every cell, so i have an if statement that checks if it should be hidden and if it is i need to change the label to the left. Which i am able to do with this code.

```
   if (checking here not relevant) { 

        cell.liveButton.hidden = YES;

        CGRect frame = cell.gameTimeLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x= 27;                         // move the label 10px to the left since no image will be present
        cell.gameTimeLabel.frame= frame;
        NSLog(@"in here");   // Checking if this code actually runs
   }
```

So when i start my app the label has not yet changed (but it prints out the message " in here"), Then i have a timer that runs the reload table once every 10 seconds. And the next time it updates itself when the console prints again "in here" THEN the labels change place. Why is that and how can i fix this so the labels are changed the first time?

Thanks for all the help!!

```
- (void) startTimer{

    [timer invalidate];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(retrieveData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) retrieveData{

    gamesInfoArray = [gamesInfoObject fetchData];  

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and in the other class to which i call the function to get the json information

```
-(void) fetchData{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

    if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
        NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li", url, (long)[responseCode statusCode]);
    }

    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

}
```

Comment: Instead of using the same cell, try creating two cells and use what you need.
One in If Statement and the other in the else statement.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code line-by-line to ensure all the variables are what you expect them to be? If "in here" is printing, perhaps one of the variables is unexpectedly `nil`.

Comment: But its not logical? why would the values not be nil after it loads the tableview again? its doing the same process again but i can check just to be sure @AaronBrager

Comment: Is the timer calling `reloadData` on the main thread?

Comment: Im not really sure what that means and how i would check that @AaronBrager

Comment: @TimoCengiz Post the code where you create the timer, and the method that gets called when the timer fires.

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay i had practise @AaronBrager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a nice and easy custom animation in viewdidload after doing reload data, for example:

```
    [yourtable reloadData];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //Change here the transition type
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionMoveIn; //Change here the animation to present again the cells

    [[yourtable layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"UITableViewReloadDataAnimationKey"];
```

That way, the reuse cells would be updated, is a little tricky but could work for you. You can change the type of the transitions to get other type of animation.

Answer (score 0):

Add left Constraints to label. Make outlet for this Constraint.

```
constLabelLeft.constant = 10; // default 30 maybe
[cell.view needsUpdateConstraints];
```

Comment: But does constraints work when working with hidden outlets? Cause i think its still there taking that " space "

Comment: You will change constant value. When image hidden. For example: If default 30, when image hidden 10.